# get latest file from S3 failing with errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to get latest zip file from the S3 bucket but when i try to copy to local directory it gives error unknown option

```sh
$ KEY=`aws s3 ls $BUCKET --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'` 
$ aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/$KEY   z:/location/folder/$key(filename)
```

but at error given unknown option z:/location

Thanks

Comment: Does the destination directory exist?

Comment: yes it does exist and contains data as well.

Comment: why dont you first cd to the location where you want to save the file and then run this `aws s3 cp s3://$BUCKET/$KEY   $key(filename)`, does this solution worked? and if i may know what is the use of z: over here? why cant you use `/location/folder/$key(filename)`

Comment: Hi,I want to automate the process either by command line or batch or someother way so i do not have to do it manually. steps are : list the latest zip file, cp it to local drive(z:/file location), then unzip it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket BUCKETNAME --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

This uses the AWS CLI to list all objects, sort them by `LastModified`, then return the Key of the most recent object.

The AWS CLI uses [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html), so it can do amazing tricks like this!

Note that the Key of an object includes the **full path within the Amazon S3 bucket**. Therefore, if you are downloading to a destination, you might first need to **create the sub-directories** on your local machine in which to store the object. Alternatively, **split the Key at the last slash** to just obtain the name of the object *without* the path, and it should save just fine into the local directory.